# I want to change background color according to status

Tags: maven-plugin

I want to change background color according to status.
If it's active then it should be green.

```
<td id="txtSuppStatus"><c:out value="${dashSupList.supplierStatus }"/></td> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkFilled()
    {
        var supplierStatus = document.getElementById("txtSuppStatus");

           if(supplierStatus == "Active")
            {
               supplierStatus.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }
           else
               {
                 document.getElementById('txtSuppStatus').setAttribute( "class", "label label-danger  label-mini" );
               } 

    }
   </script>
```

Comment: what's not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i got the answer.

```
                                            <c:choose> 
                                            <c:when test="${dashMaintenanceList.maintenanceStatus == 'In Progress'}">           
                                            <td><c:out value="${dashMaintenanceList.assetTag}"/></td>               
                                    <td><c:out value="${dashMaintenanceList.maintenanceType}"/></td>    

                               <td><span class="label label-info"><c:out value="${dashMaintenanceList.maintenanceStatus}" /></span></td>        
                                            </c:when>   

                                            <c:when test="${dashMaintenanceList.maintenanceStatus == 'Repaired'}">          
                                            <td><c:out value="${dashMaintenanceList.assetTag}"/></td>               
                                    <td><c:out value="${dashMaintenanceList.maintenanceType}"/></td>                   
                            <td><span class="label label-success  label-mini"><c:out value="${dashMaintenanceList.maintenanceStatus}" /></span></td>                
                                            </c:when>   

                                    <c:when test="${dashMaintenanceList.maintenanceStatus == 'To be initiated'}">
                                <td><c:out value="${dashMaintenanceList.assetTag}"/></td>               
                                <td><c:out value="${dashMaintenanceList.maintenanceType}"/></td>                   
                    <td><span class="label label-primary"><c:out value="${dashMaintenanceList.maintenanceStatus}" /></span></td>        
                                </c:when>


                                           </c:choose>
                                    </c:forEach>
```